# How to compile Saurik's Veency?

Tags: ios, macos, vnc, iphone-privateapi, vnc-server

I checked out Saurik's Veency code (git://git.saurik.com/veency.git) and proceeded to build it on a Mac. I tried running `./make.sh` and ended up with the error:

`./make.sh: line 4: /apl/tel/exec.sh: No such file or directory`

I also tried just running `make` but failed with the error:

`makefile:7: ../tweaks/tweak.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '../tweaks/tweak.mk'.  Stop.`

I searched on google using keywords compile, veency, build, how, but didn't find anything useful at all, or only found unanswered questions. How is this supposed to be built? Are there pre-setup steps that need to be done?

Edit: added OS info.

Comment: Edit: Tagged iphone-privateapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Niknah's Veency port](https://github.com/niknah/veency) that compiles on the Mac. Outdated but it's a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Get **cygwin,** and install the **iPhone 2.0 toolchain**.

Put all the Veency stuff in user folder, and run

> ./make.sh.

in terminal.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to mention I'm on a Mac.